# OCI runtime exec failed - Container_linux.go:348

Tags: linux, windows, docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

With Git Bash, I tried to start my docker container (a blockchain test-network, Hyperledger Fabric) on my windows 10. Docker version 18.03.1-ce.
I tried to search on google but have not found a specific answer to this issue. Appreciate any help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *probably*  a golang version issue. Please make sure you meet all the prerequisites listed http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/prereqs.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I checked an my Go-version is go1.10.3 windows/amd64. However, the GOPATH is set to a go-directory under my user account (Users/X/Go), while the Fabric folder downloaded is on my Desktop. Could this be the issue? Do you have a suggested solution? I will update the post with some more photos. Thanks!

Comment: The file location for the Fabric folder is this: C:\Users\X\Desktop\Sawtooth\curl\fabric-samples